# Mirror modifier issue after applied

Tags: mirror-modifier

I am new to blender and I am currently working on a fun project. I used the mirror modifier here and I didn't notice the issue days after applying it when I was weight painting. I noticed that there are two shades of the mesh and its probably because of the mirror modifier. I have seen many talk about this but the thing is my modifier have already been applied days before so I cant control Z. Does anyone know what I can do to remove this? :)

Edit, Here is the picture: https://i.imgur.com/3KMsMvx.jpg

[image]

Comment: Hello, what do you mean by "there are two shades of the mesh"? Maybe share your object: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I think we'll need to see your Blend file. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page. Then [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/310872/edit) your question here and paste the link into it.

Comment: It could be double faces (if you mirrored whole character) or flipped normals. Can you show us normals orientation?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: make sure that you don't have inner faces, if it's not the problem please share your file

Comment: Also select all in Edit mode and press M > Merge by Distance in order to merge overlapping vertices

Comment: Thank you for the comments! I needed to use M for merge. Thx for the help!